# I need to carry forward the primary table's primary key to a foreign key field in dependent table

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have 2 entities Customer and address please find the code below, I have omitted boiler plate code for simplicity.

```
public class Customer  implements java.io.Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3116894694769321104L;
     private short customerId;
     private Address address;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String email;
     private boolean active;
     private Date createDate;
     private Date lastUpdate;


    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @Column(name="customer_id", unique=true, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)

    public short getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(short customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

        @JoinColumn(name="address_id", unique=false, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)

    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
```

and Address class is :

```
public class Address  implements java.io.Serializable {


    // Fields    

     private short addressId;
     private short customerId;
     private String address;
     private String address2;
     private String district;
     private String postalCode;
     private String phone;
     private Date lastUpdate;
     private Set<Customer> customers_1 = new HashSet<Customer>(0);


    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Address() {
    }

   // Property accessors
    @Id
    @Column(name="address_id", unique=true, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)

    public short getAddressId() {
        return this.addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(short addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    /**
     * ??????what goes here
     */
    public short getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerId the customerId to set
     */
    public void setCustomerId(short customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
```

I need to persist the customer id as a foreign key in address table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`@ManyToOne`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) relationship with `Customer`. So, instead of `customerId` in Java code you will be operates with `Customer` object, but at database level Hibernate will use foreign key to table with customer.